# Get index of parent object in nested object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
[
    { 
        elements: [
            { id: '123', field: 'value' }
            { id: '456', field: 'value' }
        ]
    }
    { 
        elements: [
            { id: '789', field: 'value' }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I need to get the index of the first level object searching by an id: 
searching for `id = '456'` should give me `0`, `id = '789'` should give me `1`

Comment: any code of your searching?

Comment: I don't know how to start with that

Comment: Basically, you want to get the `id` of the first item in your `elements` arrays ?

Comment: there's no built-in way to do this. You need to loop on the array

Comment: @YassineBadache No, the ID is the value I know. Depending on that id I need to get the index number of its parent object

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `findIndex()` and `some()`

```js
var arr = [{
  elements: [{
    id: '123',
    field: 'value'
  }, {
    id: '456',
    field: 'value'
  }]
}, {
  elements: [{
    id: '789',
    field: 'value'
  }]
}]

var i = arr.findIndex(function(o) {
  return o.elements.some(function(e) {
    return e.id == 456;
  })
})

console.log(i)
```

Comment: `findIndex` might not exist in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Get the feeling that something could be fixed to rethink this. But who knows.
456 should give u id 1 and so should 789 aswell.

```
var mapped = whatEverObject[0].elements.map(function(obj){ //0 = first 
 return obj.id;
})

console.log(mapped.indexOf(456)) // will give you 1 since id:123 is id 0 in the first elements array.
```

Comment: I'm thinking of the first level object. So 456 is in the first object, which should give me a `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a lookup table. It will be much faster if you do several lookups.

### [Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jpf07xg2/)

```
var table = makeNestedLookupTable(example);
// table[789] would be 1 if the array in the question were "example"

function makeNestedLookupTable(data) {
    return data.reduce(function(lookup, obj, topIndex) {
        return obj.elements.reduce(function(lookup, element) {
            lookup[element.id] = topIndex;
            return lookup;
        }, lookup);
    }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function `getIndex` which loops through the array and matches the id of the element with the given id and returns the index.This solution will work in all browsers.

```
var arr = [
    { 
        elements: [
            { id: '123', field: 'value' }
            { id: '456', field: 'value' }
        ]
    }
    { 
        elements: [
            { id: '789', field: 'value' }
        ]
    }
];

function getIndex(arr, id) {
    var i, ii, len, elemlen;
    for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        elements = arr[i].elements;
        for (ii = 0, elemlen = elements.length; ii < elemlen; ii++) {
            if (elements[ii].id === id) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}

var index = getIndex(arr, '456');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic code where you can send an array and the lookup attribute:

```
function giveLevel(a,attr){
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  var o = a[i];
  var tmp = JSON.stringify(o);
  if(tmp.indexOf(attr)!==-1){
    return i;
  }
}
}

var a = [{elements: [
            { id: '123', field: 'value' },
            { id: '456', field: 'value' }
        ]
    },
    { 
        elements: [
            { id: '789', field: 'value' }
        ]
    }
];

giveLevel(a,'"id":"789"'); // returns 1
```